# Sensu, Google Chat Handler for Multi Chat Rooms

Tags: sensu, google-hangouts, google-chat

Is there any **google chat module** to send alerts via sensu's google chat handler to more than one room (chat room)?
Ex: As like in Slack we have multi-slack-handler.rb handler is there to trigger alerts on multiple channels via subscriptions which we defined./
Is this same kind of thing Possible with google chat??

In my case, I have created two channels in Sensu (sensu-core open source edition) but I am getting alerts in only one channel after few minutes I am getting alerts on another channel as well but it sends alerts in only one channel at a time. How can we get alerts in all the channels on sensu with google hangout handler?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this module: https://github.com/anandtripathi5/google-chat-handler. It is a simple handler which you can add to your logger and configure the level of chat as required. Adding it multiple times with different Gchat room webhooks will push logs to multiple Gchat rooms simultaneously.